# Using Both wifi and Local network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ethernet

Hope all doin good..
Kindly i need a help in how to use my laptop to access the Internet via wifi while i am using the same laptop to access my company network with access to the all VLANs via Ethernet port.
I think i need to add routing but am not aware of how to do it.
I did one thing, i add an interface metric:2 to the Ethernet and 1 to the wifi, but in this case i can access now the internet with only the vLan that i am on it "10.160.7.x" and i can not reach other VLANs like "10.160.6.x, 10.160.3.x, ... "

Anybody can help me what shall i do ?

All thanks and appreciations...

Comment: depends on the OS. Newer Windows will set the metrics automatically and you don't need to do anything

Comment: What is the Operating System of your Laptop?

Comment: windows 10 enterprise 64bit

Comment: @phuclv , i already did that but not works as i want.

Comment: @phuclv , i need to keep connecting and accessing my all company VLANs from my laptop and access the internet via wifi at the same time.

Comment: Are both interfaces using static addresses? can you show us a copy of your routing table? Run `IPConfig /all`  and `route print` and show us the results here. And last, is the wifi your default route?